# How do I negate the use of 'Actions." when performing actions in libGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have been learning libGDX, and following people's tutorials and such, but for actions, I keep seeing examples for actions such as:

```
actor.addAction(sequence(moveTo(200, 100, 2), color(Color.RED, 6), delay(0.5f), rotateTo(180, 5)));
```

Where as when I write it, I must include 'Action.' before every action call, such as:

```
startGameButton.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.delay(0.5f), Actions.alpha(1, 1f)));
```

How do people manage to not need the use of the 'Action.' bit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a [static import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html):

```
import static com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions.*;
```

Comment: Oh, I never knew those existed. Thanks a ton.